# Can't find uniforms in the fragmentShader lwgl 3

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl

the problem is in the title.

**Console error**

```
LWJGL Version: 3.0.0 build 90
GLFW Version: 3.2.0 Win32 WGL EGL VisualC DLL
OpenGL Version: 4.0.0 NVIDIA 372.70
java.lang.Exception: Can't find uniform: lightColor
at com.ms.shaders.ShaderProgram.getUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:50)
at com.ms.shaders.Shaders.createUniforms(Shaders.java:32)
```

**ShaderProgram**

```
public class ShaderProgram {

private int programID;
private int vertexShaderID;
private int fragmentShaderID;

private Map<String, Integer> uniforms;

public ShaderProgram() {

    uniforms = new HashMap<>();
}

public void createProgram() throws Exception {

    programID = glCreateProgram();

    if(programID == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create program");
    }
}

public void createShaders(String vertexFile, String fragmentFile) throws Exception {

    vertexShaderID = shadersLoader(vertexFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

}

protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String name) {
    glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, name);
}

public void getUniformLocation(String uniform) throws Exception {

    int uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, uniform);

    if(uniformLocation < 0) {
        throw new Exception("Can't find uniform: " + uniform);
    }

    uniforms.put(uniform, uniformLocation);
}

public void floatUniforms(String uniform, float value) {
    glUniform1f(uniforms.get(uniform), value);
}

public void intUniforms(String uniform, int value) {
    glUniform1i(uniforms.get(uniform), value);
}

public void booleanUniforms(String uniform, boolean value) {

    float load = 0;
    if(value) {
        load = 1;
    }

    glUniform1f(uniforms.get(uniform), load);
}

public void vectorUniforms(String uniform, Vector3f value) {
    glUniform3f(uniforms.get(uniform), value.x, value.y, value.z);
}

public void matrixUniforms(String uniform, Matrix4f value) {

    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    value.get(buffer);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.get(uniform), false, buffer);
}

public int shadersLoader(String shader, int type) throws Exception {

    int shaderID = glCreateShader(type);

    glShaderSource(shaderID, shader);

    glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if(glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to compile Shader: " + glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 1024));
    }

    glAttachShader(programID, shaderID);

    return shaderID;
}

public void linkProgram() throws Exception {

    glLinkProgram(programID);
    if(glGetProgrami(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS) == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to link program: " + glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, 1024));
    }

    glValidateProgram(programID);
    if(glGetProgrami(programID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to validate program: " + glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, 1024));
    }
}

public void bind() {
    glUseProgram(programID);
}

public void unbind() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}

public void cleanUp() {

    unbind();

    if(programID != 0) {
        if(vertexShaderID != 0) {
            glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
            glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
        }

        if(fragmentShaderID != 0) {
            glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
            glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
        }

        glDeleteProgram(programID);
    }
}
}
```

**Shaders**

```
public class Shaders extends ShaderProgram {

private static final String VERTEX_SHADER = "vertexShader.txt";
private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER = "fragmentShader.txt";

public void init() throws Exception {

    createProgram();
    createShaders(FileLoader.loadResources(VERTEX_SHADER), FileLoader.loadResources(FRAGMENT_SHADER));
    linkProgram();

    createUniforms();
}

public void bindAttributes() {

    bindAttribute(0, "position");
    bindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
    bindAttribute(2, "normal");
}

public void createUniforms() throws Exception {

    getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
    getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
    getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
    getUniformLocation("lightPosition");
    getUniformLocation("lightColor");
    getUniformLocation("shineDamper");
    getUniformLocation("reflectivity");
}
}
```

**fragmentShader.txt**

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 outTextureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;

void main()
{
vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

float nDotl = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.2);
vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColor;

vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
float dampFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
vec3 finalSpecular = dampFactor * reflectivity * lightColor;

outColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * texture(textureSampler, outTextureCoords) +     vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);
}
```

If i try to remove lightColor uniform the error switch in the shineDamper uniform.

**EDITED**

If i put all in the Renderer class the problem don't exist... Why?

This is the class where I set uniforms:

**UniformCreation**

```
public class UniformsCreation {

private Transformation transformation;
private ShaderProgram shaders;

private float FOV = (float) Math.toRadians(60.0f);
private float zNEAR = 0.01f;
private float zFAR = 1000.0f;

public UniformsCreation() {

    transformation = new Transformation();
    shaders = new ShaderProgram();
}

public void renderer(Entity[] entity, Camera camera, Light light) {

    createProjectionMatrix();
    createTransformationMatrix(entity);
    createViewMatrix(camera);
    createLight(light, Texture.getShineDamper(), Texture.getReflection());
}

public Matrix4f createProjectionMatrix() {

    Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    projectionMatrix = transformation.createProjectionMatrix(
            FOV, 
            Main.getWIDTH(), 
            Main.getHEIGHT(), 
            zNEAR, 
            zFAR);

    shaders.matrixUniforms("projectionMatrix", projectionMatrix);

    return projectionMatrix;
}

public Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Entity[] entity) {

    Matrix4f transformationMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    for(Entity entities : entity) {

        transformationMatrix = transformation.createTransformationMatrix(
                entities.getPosition(), 
                entities.getRotation(), 
                entities.getScale());

        shaders.matrixUniforms("transformationMatrix", transformationMatrix);
        entities.getMesh().render();
    }

    return transformationMatrix;
}

public Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {

    Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    viewMatrix = transformation.createViewMatrix(camera);

    shaders.matrixUniforms("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);

    return viewMatrix;
}

public void createLight(Light light, float damper, float reflectivity) {

    shaders.vectorUniforms("lightPosition", light.getPosition());
    shaders.vectorUniforms("lightColor", light.getColor());
    shaders.floatUniforms("shineDamper", damper);
    shaders.floatUniforms("reflectivity", reflectivity);
}
}
```

If I remove the lightColor, shineDamper and reflectivity uniforms the error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ms.shaders.ShaderProgram.matrixUniforms(ShaderProgram.java:83)
at com.ms.utils.UniformsCreation.createProjectionMatrix(UniformsCreation.java:46)
at com.ms.utils.UniformsCreation.renderer(UniformsCreation.java:29)
at com.ms.renderer.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:42)
at com.ms.MineSmooth.gameLoop(MineSmooth.java:93)
at com.ms.MineSmooth.run(MineSmooth.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should check not only the uniform variable but also the other variable you used. If one variable relative to the lightColor or shineDamper is invalid, then the uniform varialbe will be omited.

Answer (score 0):

Negative uniform locations are [perfectly cromulent](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#glGetUniformLocation_and_glGetActiveUniform):

> Although not strictly a mistake, some wonder why glGetUniformLocation​
>   returns -1. If there is a uniform that you are not using, the driver
>   will optimize your uniform out. Drivers are really good at optimizing
>   code. If you are using your uniform, but none of the values computed
>   from that uniform contribute to any output from the shader (directly
>   or indirectly), the uniform will usually be optimized out.
>
> Typically this is not a problem, since if you pass -1 instead of a
>   valid uniform location to the glUniform​ calls, they will quietly do
>   nothing anyway. But you will also get -1 if you misspell the variable
>   name to glGetUniformLocation​, so keep this in mind.

Enumerate uniform names via the [shader introspection API](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection#Uniforms_and_blocks) to check for spelling mistakes.

Comment: The name of all uniforms it's correct, the problem is only in the uniforms in the fragmentShader file.